# Fusedlocationproviderclient method getcurrentlocation() is working fine for me but

Tags: android-studio, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am using the above mention method like

```
 mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
                            mFusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY,null).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                                 
                                    if (location != null) {
                                       
                                        userCurrentLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                                        getAddress(userCurrentLatLng);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

in the cancellation token parameter i am passing null so is this going make any difference or i have to pass cancellation token in here. still i am getting the current location.

please suggest do i have to pass the parameter or null will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this,i have tried its working fine
`mFusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(
PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY,
object : CancellationToken() {
override fun isCancellationRequested(): Boolean {
return false
}

```
                override fun onCanceledRequested(onTokenCanceledListener: OnTokenCanceledListener): CancellationToken {
                    return this
                }
            }).addOnSuccessListener { location: Location ->
             //handle your location here
            }`
```